# How to remove the unwanted new lines in GitHub::gist?

Tags: html, github, gist, syntaxhighlighter

I am trying to use GitHub:Gist as a code highlighter for displaying my example codes in my html blog in my website.

But what the rendered version in my website puts extra unwanted newlines after each character in my code. [see a screenshot below]

Here you can see my source code and source gist, if you need to: https://saeedmirshekari.com/blog/test/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause for this failure.

In my `css` I needed to remove the following from style.css and everything work as expectred.

```
abbr, time, span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* display: block; */
}
```